# Avoid creation of objects through SAP GUI

Tags: abap, sap-erp, sap-hr

As a tester, I'd like to know whether it is possible to restrict the manual creation of new objects by the user. The restriction should be done programatically in ABAP, not by removal of permissions.

Background information: we have quite complex objects which are hard to set up manually. Therefore we have implemented a wizard, which does all the condition checking etc. when creating the object. Also, if the wizard shall work, the user must have appropriate permissions to create the object.

Is it possible to remove the object type for that complex object from the list which appears when creating a new object (pressing the New button)?

As I'm only a tester for this part of our software, I can't show any existing code. I just got the feedback "It's not possible" and that's hard to believe for me at the moment. Usability really suffers, because people try to create those objects manually and can't make it work.

I also don't need a working code example, just a hint (class or method or setting) for the developer where to find a solution. I'll then insist that he implements it :-)

**Update**

Today, the user can click the "New" icon. Then, a dialog appears with 4 choices. 3 choices are for simple objects which he shall create like this. However, the first item in that list is for the complex object, which is impossible to create manually (why we have the wizard). I'd like to know whether it is possible to remove that item from the list programatically.

[image: Screenshot of what I want to achieve]

Comment: Without any information about whatever function you wish to be disabled in detail, it's hard to tell...

Comment: @vwegert: I've updated the question and added a screenshot for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

ᵺṓᵯᶏᵴ, the information you have provided is still a bit vague.  However, here is an idea that may work for you.

- It might not be possible to *completely* automate this process, but you could ask your developer to enhance the code that processes the New button, so that it would reject any attempt to bypass the wizard for the first item on the list.
- Your developer can tell you if it is feasible in your case, to have the enhancement raise an error (message of type E) to stop the user from proceeding.
- This would have to be combined with end-user training to tell people to avoid the New button for that item, and use the wizard instead

Answer (score 0):

ᵺṓᵯᶏᵴ, it looks like a custom dialog so it should be possible to remove it the option, alternatively if it is a standard dialog in a SAP app there is always a way to restrict it, it can be as simple as disallow entry from specific transaction codes. for example the developer could set a variable at the start of the wizard and then check for that variable when creating the object, if it not there he can show a dialog "Please use the Wizard we carefully crafted for your use......" Ok maybe you wont say all of that but you get it.

So the answer to your query is yes it can be done but the approach will depend on what it is your changing custom or standard object etc,.

Later..